# Colloquy + Google Talk = Possible?

Tags: google-apps

Has anyone tried to get Colloquy to work with Google Talk? Have searched online, but couldn't find any useful articles.

PS. Not sure if this is the right place to ask for such a question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's not going to work. Colloquy is a client for the [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irc) protocol (also [SILC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_(protocol)) and [ICB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Citizen%27s_Band), both of which are rarely used). Google Talk uses [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) (aka Jabber) for its text chat, which Colloquy doesn't support.

If you want a 3rd party client for Google Talk, anything that supports XMPP/Jabber will do, but keep in mind this works *only for the text chat*. The VoIP capabilities require the Google client or website. iChat includes a Google Talk account option, you just need to fill in your Google ID and password:

[image: iChat account set up]

Another popular Mac option is [Adium](http://adium.im/), a multi-protocol IM client, that will do Google Talk as well as AIM, MSN, Yahoo and others.

Comment: while IRC/Jabber bridges do exist, it's probably not what the asker intended. +1

Comment: Good point, I forgot about that, but it does sound like the OP was asking about using Colloquy as a Google Talk client, not sending IRC chat to a Jabber chat, which the bridges do.